# AngularJS - refresh element causes reload ng-view

Tags: angularjs

I'm tring to refresh an element in AngularJS but the following code hides whole ng-view content

```
var firstModule = angular.module('myModule', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']);

    var mainDataServiceInjectParams = ['$http', '$q'];

    var mainFactory = function ($http, $q) {
        var mainDataService = {};
        mainDataService.refreshStatus = function (id) {
            return $http.get('/api/values/' + id).then(function (results) {
                return results.data;
            });
        };

        return mainDataService;
    };

    mainFactory.$inject = mainDataServiceInjectParams;
    firstModule.factory('mainService', mainFactory);

    firstModule.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http, mainService) {
        $scope.TST = {};

        $scope.clickMe = function (id) {
            $scope.loading = true;

            mainService.refreshStatus(id).then(function (results) {
                $scope.TST = 'abc';
                $scope.loading = false;
            });
        }
    });

   firstModule.config(function ($routeProvider) {
       $routeProvider.when("/status/:id", {
             templateUrl: 't.html',
             controller: 'myCtrl'
         });
   });
```

t.html

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-mini" href="#" ng-click="clickMe(321)">Refresh</a>
{{TST}}
```

whole `t.html` content disappears after click on the `Refresh` link. Why ?

### EDIT

I just had to remove `href="#"` inside `<a>` from the `t.html`

Comment: I had the same problem when I was using ngRoute with angularjs, using angular-ui-router solved many routing problems, in this case there is a function allowing to refresh a state with same params you should checkout

Comment: Also if your html content dépends on the GET result, consider using a $scope.loading value that make a switch between a loading state and displaying content because it can occur that on a refresh the html page is rendered before the content arrive from server and then nothing is displayed, thats asynchronous issues

Comment: I added the $scope.loading = true and false (see the edited post), without result

Comment: you need to add a loading div with ng-show="loading" and a content div with ng-hide="!loading" in your html